# How to stop showing messages from procedures in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How to stop showing messages from procedure?

Currently, the problem is I have created a stored procedure `Procedure A`. It executes another `procedure B` from its code, and the `B` procedure executes yet other procedures C,D,E from its code.

The problem is when the `A` procedure executes, it shows 4 result sets like 0,1 or another values. But I want to show only the result from procedure A. How can I achieve this? I can't change the other procedures B,C,D,E because they also perform their individual tasks.

If you need clarification please ask.

Comment: you have to create a separate procedure for that particular scenario only without using BCDE. to avoid conflict.

Comment: What exactly does it show? Is it show recordsets or is it showing "x record(s) affected"? You can try adding `SET NOCOUNT ON;` to the topmost SP

Comment: Show messages from where? SSMS? Your code? How are you calling the SP?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the followings:

1. if any of the sub procedures is returning only one row set and it is static (same columns with the same type are always returned), you can materialized the result set in temporary tables (or table variables)

   For example, let's say that procedure X returns a table with two int columns. You 
   materialized the result like this:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE #X
   (
       A INT
       ,B INT
   );

   INSERT INTO #X
   EXEC usp_X;
   ```
2. Add additional parameter to the sub procedures or use any of the existing ones to not return the row set(s) if certain option is passed.

   For example, add `@MiscSettings` parameter to your existing procedure X:

   ```
   ALTER PROCEDURE usp_X AS
   (
        @Param01 INT
        ,@Parame02 VARCHAR(12)
        ,...
        ,@MiscSettings NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
   )
   ```

   The parameter is not mandatory, so you are not going to break any existing reference. Then in the procedure you can check if `[DoNotReturnResultSet]` string is passed in the `@MiscSettings` to not return the result sets. Existing references will continue to work because by default the row sets are returned.

   ```
   IF Option Is Not Passed 
   BEGIN;
        SELECT ...
   END;
   ```

In both ways you can suffer if someone change the code of the sub routines. For example, if a type of returned column is changed, or someone add additional row set without checking if your special option is passed.

Note, in the second technique, if you do not like to add additional parameter, you can use some of the existing strings (for example). Just check if the string contains your option and then replace it.